# Getting keys from JCS Cache

Tags: java, jcs

I am using JCS cache for performance enhancement.There is an issue when I need to maintain a set of keys because the type of storage I use is generally offline storage to the disk.
Is there a way to get the set of keys alone from the cache as I can with a hashmap,so that I can automate the process of getting the data from the cache,since I dont care about what kind of data comes out of cache because the metadata of the object is stored within the cache object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it myself,

In a group cache access,using putInGroup and getFromGroup there is a method getGroupKeys(groupname),which enables us to get the keys alone from the group within the cache region.The API documentation will greatly help in this case.

http://commons.apache.org/jcs/apidocs/index.html

Comment: but is there a way to get the list of all keys in the cache (i.e. not just in a given group)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of keys by accessing the `MemoryCache` of the `CompositeCache` instance of your cache, this way: `CompositeCacheManager.getInstance().getCache(cache_name).getMemoryCache().getKeyArray()`